# Data passing by using sound waves(ultrasound wave)

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I have one project where have to send data via sound wave, I saw many links but nowhere its mention how to use them. Please help me to implement the same.
https://medium.com/@aldychris/flutter-and-audio-qr-implementation-e378d55f7dbe

Comment: Quick searching comes up with this: https://github.com/quiet/QuietModemKit ... probably a good place to start.

Comment: You can try chirp sdk to achieve it. You can find the example flutter project in this link : https://github.com/chirp/chirp-flutter